# How to blame correct file and line at development app served with Create React App?

Tags: reactjs, bundle

I have an APP that I developed some time ago. It fires up a node development enviroment with `react-scripts start`. If my memory is not faiing me the errors on said development enviroment used to blame the code file and line but now it just spits 'bundle.js line xxxxx:x' that has no debbuging use for me.

How do I disable the bundling or make it so I can find the correct file and line?